# how do I check if a table already exists

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database

when I run the application I want my application to automatically create databases and tables, but in this code my application only creates databases without tables

so I made it when the button was pressed, at that time there was also data in the form of an insert query that would be executed by the addBio function, but that always returns an existing table error so how to handle this

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "biodata.db";
    private static final String TABEL_NAME = "biodata";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABEL_NAME + " ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, lahir TEXT, kelamin TEXT, hobi TEXT, alamat TEXT);";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABEL_NAME + "'");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addBio (String bio) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(bio);
        Log.d("TAGINI", bio);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TambahActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnSimpan;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private EditText nama, lahir, hobi, alamat, jk;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tambah);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        nama = findViewById(R.id.nama);
        lahir = findViewById(R.id.tanggal_lahir);
        jk = findViewById(R.id.jk);
        hobi = findViewById(R.id.hobi);
        alamat = findViewById(R.id.alamat);
        btnSimpan = findViewById(R.id.btnSimpan);

        btnSimpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO biodata (id, nama, lahir, kelamin, hobi, alamat) VALUES('', '" +
                        nama.getText().toString() +"','"+
                        lahir.getText().toString()+"','"+
                        jk.getText().toString()+"','"+
                        hobi.getText().toString()+"','"+
                        alamat.getText().toString()+"');";
                databaseHelper.addBio(sql);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope that when I run the application the database and table will automatically be created in it

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: you should remove id from the sql statement, '' is not a good value for id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write an insert `sql`. Use `db.insert` instead.

```
  btnSimpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 addBio(nama.getText().toString());
        });
```

In addBio

```
public void addBio (String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
    insertValues.put("name", name);
    db.insert("biodata", null, insertValues);
 }
```